# Converting existing Rails 4 app to engine (without namespacing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling to find a guide for converting an existing Rails 4 app into an Engine without namespacing. Everywhere I've looked - even including the official Rails guide (edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) - seem 100% focussed on namespacing whereas there is only a passing mention of doing the same in a non-namespaced fashion. Also mostly relating to Rails 3.

As well as this it is only really dealing with setting an engine up from scratch, whereas I'm looking for pointers on exactly how to tackle the conversion from an existing app to a mountable engine.

Specifically at the moment I'm having issues getting the host app to access any of the models within the mounted app, and having hacked around for a while I'm feeling a bit lost.

Any pointers or advice would be gratefully received!

Thanks.

Comment: everything you put in `/app` will be loaded, namespaced or not

Comment: Thanks... I was aware of that but struggling to get anything from /app to be accessible from within the host app. Hopefully looking for a guide or some pointers which don't completely revolve around the namespaceing method.